# Tell EF to handle a composite index that is unique

Tags: entity-framework-5

I set a 3-column index that must be unique in my table. How can I tell EF that? I'm currently getting a `DbUpdateException` when trying to save the changes.

`Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'sm.SkillAssignations' with unique index 'IX_SkillAssignations'. The duplicate key value is (8285, 1, 2, 2).\r\nThe statement has been terminated.`

Answer (score 1):

In order to avoid the exception check if an entity with the unique index value you want to insert already exists:

```
if (!context.SkillAssignations.Any(s =>
        s.Value1 == newSkillAssignation.Value1 &&
        s.Value2 == newSkillAssignation.Value2 &&
        s.Value3 == newSkillAssignation.Value3))
    context.SkillAssignations.Add(newSkillAssignation);
else
    // your own error handling
    // - or do you want to UPDATE the existing entity in this case?
```

It could still fail if someone else inserts an entity with that key between the `Any` call (EXISTS query) and the `Add` (INSERT statement). I am not aware of any magic that would save you this check.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah. I still need to catch the exception.